# What's the difference between .env file and actual environment variable?

Tags: python, environment-variables

Say I have some API-key in my project that I don't wanna share into git repository, then I have to use environment variables. Now, why shouldn't I blatantly set the environmental variable on my local machine (like PATH) instead of making .env file and downloading python-dotenv library to my project for the sake of doing actually the same thing?

Comment: Because `os.environ['API-KEY'] = 'stuff'` will be committed to VCS (exposing `stuff` to the world), unlike your `.env` file.

Comment: Because you would presumably check in that code to the repo, and "stuff" would be visible? Unless I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: You shouldn't do that because you explicitly said you don't want the secret to be in git...

Comment: I have to apologise, everyone. I thought that `os.environ['API-KEY'] = 'stuff'` would actually set the environment variable, so that it can be accessed anywhere, just like python PATH environment variable

Comment: You should set the variable in your shell login file.

Comment: I don't use linux, hence I can't set the variable in "shell login file" and it wasn't even mentioned

Answer (score 1):

`.env` file is just manner to store this variables in file that can use packages for example [dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) to read as an `os.environ` varaible. so in short it is manner of storage of configuration.

many times your gitignore will have `.env` thus users can store the API key with `.env` file on local machine to help ease of use and ensuring dont accidently leave api keys within committed git files

if you just do a bear `os.environ['API-KEY'] = 'stuff'` within code it will store in commited git file (and env variables are there within a run of python process, not their permanently between sessions, thus why storing in file is preferred)

with this there are types of way to store configuration [dynaconf](https://www.dynaconf.com/) is a great package and package shows many of the other types of configuration files

Comment: thanks, kamster, it provides some light. I asked the question in a wrong way, because I thought that `os.environ['API-KEY'] = 'stuff'` would store the `API-KEY` environment variable, just like, say, vscode path, so it can be accessed anywhere. And of course I didn't mean to write this line explicitly in the code.
You said that it is convenient for users to have their `.env` file - that's one advantage. Could You provide any more advantages?

Comment: so i guess my question for you would be what other options/ideas looking at? will help answer better and comparing what advantages something like `.env` can have